# How to prevent from opening the same link again when clicking on back/forward in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

after I opened a page where it says that my request has been accepted and then navigate to another link and then press back on the browser, I don't want to go back to the same link again where my request has been accepted but instead redirect to home.

My first approach is I use this HostListener in my request-accepted-component

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    console.log('Back button pressed');
  }
```

But this only works when I click back/forward FROM the request-accepted-component but won't invoke when I click back TO the request-accepted-component.
I can use this HostListener for every other component but I think this is not the way to go.

Any other ideas?
I thought about creating a guard to prevent from going back to the request-accepted-component by clicking on back/forward on the browser.

Comment: Would `skipLocationChange` work for you? From wherever you are doing router navigation to the accepted page, you can skip the router path being pushed to browser history.

Comment: Show redirect of the request confirmation page. You can replace url in history there.